# building a neural network on nested input data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to build a binary classification model using a neural network. However my input data has bunch of categorical variables which have numerical values.
Does any one have any ideas or suggestions on how to deal or build a neural network for such nested hierarchical input data?
I know I can make dummy variables for categorical values however their associated numerical values won't be represented by that method. Does anyone have any suggestions on handling such datasets?

here's an example of my input data

```
{
  "id1": [
    {
      "type": [
        {
          "type_a": {
            "val1": 0.060,
            "val2": 0.04,
            "val3": 0.046},
          },


        {
          "type_b": {
            "val1": 0.086462,
            "val2": 0.53847,
            "val3": 0.3847},   
          },


          {
          "type_c": {
            "val1": 0.06086462,
            "val2": 0.046153847,
            "val3": 0.046153847},   
          },
        ]
    }
    ,


    {
      "query": [
        {
          "var1": {
            "val": 1
            
          },


        {
          "var2": {
            "val": 2,
            
          },


          {
          "var3": {
            "val": 3,
            
          },
        ]
"id2":
[...
...
]
    }
```

Comment: What should your expected dataset look like?

Comment: the predicted column would either be a 1 or 0. So I am just trying to classify them given the values of each unique 'ID' in the data. What I am trying to figure is how to use this data in a neural net. any suggestions on that?

Comment: I can't answer this directly as of now, but a suggestion: pandas has a method: pd.json_normalize(), that unpacks nested data like this into tabular form. If you need to unpack iterables inside your dataframe (such as tuples, lists), you can also use pd.explode() in that case as well. I suggest this (if it's possible) because if you can get this into a pandas dataframe, it's really simple to convert dataframes back to tf tensors. I know it doesn't answer your question directly, but preprocessing is the best way to deal with this imo.

Comment: @AndrewJaeyoung thanks man, they seem like good suggestions. I was just concerned about ingesting categorical data as it normally needs to encoded. I will try your methods and see if it helps and works out in developing the neural net

Comment: Is the model only classifying input data as one of the nested classes?

Comment: the model is classifying this input data as a binary class, for eg id1: class 1, id2: class 2 etc